# Jackson create object by class name

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

Is there opportunity to read from json class name and create and object?

Here is what I mean:

I have an interface

```
public interface Converter {
    void process();
}
```

Next I also have some data class

```
public class Source {
    private String service;
    private String path;
    private Converter converter;
}
```

And a class that implements Converter interface

```
public class DataConverter implements Converter {
    public void process() {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

Last but not least. This is part of my json:

```
"source": {
    "service": "VIS",
    "path": "/",
    "converter": "DataConverter"
}
```

So the idea is while reading Json via Jackson's `mapper.readValue` create a `DataConverter` so it will be available from the `Data` class via getter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing custom serialisers and deserialisers, and then annotating the field in your `Source` class. To do this you need to implement the [`Converter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html) interface. The documentation suggests:

> NOTE: implementors are strongly encouraged to extend StdConverter instead of directly implementing Converter, since that can help with default implementation of typically boiler-plate code.

So what you want to do is something like this for the custom Serialiser:

```
public class ConverterSerializer extends StdConverter<Converter, String> {

@Override
public String convert(Converter value) {
    if(value instanceof DataConverter) {
        return "DataConverter";
    } ...

    return "";
}
```

}

And then annotate the value with `@JsonSerialize`:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ConverterSerializer.class)
private Converter converter;
```

The same applies for deserialising but you would implement an `StdConverter<String,Converter>` for which the convert method will take a String and return a `Converter`. You would then annotate the converter field with `@JsonDeserialize` and reference the converter.

Comment: Thanks for showing the way. I needed Deserilizer, and it's implementation is a little bit different. But I've find the solution :)